# Jquery change event firing on ready when password saved on browser

Tags: jquery

```
$("#txtinsurancePassword").change(function() {
    isPasswordUpdated = true;
    alert('Hello');
});
```

my code is above

Comment: i am using input type textbox change event

Comment: Try `$("#txtinsurancePassword").val('').change(function() {`. Set empty value before binding event

Comment: Which browser? Can you replicate it on jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Delete `isPasswordUpdated=true;` and try again.

The jQuery .change() method is activated when the value of the input is changed. Your system may not recognize "isPasswordUpdated", which is why it isn't working.

Hope this helps. For more info, check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_change.asp)